# Android rename retrieved image file

Tags: android, image, file

I have an image path, say

> ```
> /storage/emulated/0/PurTab/2148094.jpg
> ```

I want to get this image to file and rename it to **XYZ.jpg** and get it in a file.

What I tried was

```
//get file
File photo = new File(baseApp.getObserver().getTempImageFilePath());

//resave file with new name
File newFile = new File("XYZ.jpg");
photo.renameTo(newFile);
```

But not working. 
how to do this..... ??

Answer (score 0):

First you check your AndroidManifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

this both permission are required in AndroidManifest file.

if both permission are available in your AndroidManifest than check your change file exist or not.

```
if(photo.exist())
{
-- change file name logic
}
```

Than change your file name are done.